# Running tests from VS Express 2013 in Team City

Tags: c#, unit-testing, teamcity, visual-studio-express

I've created a unit tests project in visual studio express 2013 as part of a larger solution. I'm already using Team City to automate the building of the solution, but I'm trying to see if I can run these tests in a build step on team city.

I've looked at either MSTest or Nunit, but neither seem right for the built-in unit test framework in vs express.

Any advice or if this is even possible would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit:** I tried using MSTest for team city, however the files that it said were required for it to run using team city did not seem to be present when I tried to find them. The tests in question are running on VS Express 2013 using the project explorer

Comment: Why would MSTest not work? It works fine with the tests in VS2013 at least in the non-free versions.

Comment: What's the build log output?